# No results returned from query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count how many records in a mysql db using a query with a where condition. Unfortunately, the code I am using is not producing any results.

If i enter the query directly into myphpadmin, it shows there are 78 records. I am confused as to why it is not working. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Many thanks

```
<?php
$result1 = mysqli_query("SELECT count(*) FROM act WHERE activity = 'New Intake' AND new = '1'");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
$num = $rows;
?>
```

Comment: Where do you connect to the DB? What is the value of `$result` and `$rows`? What are you defining as "is not working"?

Comment: @user1532468 did you getting result if you remove where condition check your table name if yes try like like this new =1

Comment: Where is the connection? `mysqli_query($conn, $query);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.`connection` link is missing in query.(first parameter).

2.Use alias inside query.

3.Assign counted value to varibale.

4.`echo` the variable to see the result.

Do like below:-

```
<?php
 // provide db connection object as first parameter and use alias for count(*)
 $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT count(*) as total FROM act WHERE activity = 'New Intake' AND new = '1'"); 
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
 $num = $rows['total']; // assign counted value to varibale

 echo $num; // echo the variable to see the result.
?>
```

***Note:-*** Your code is wide-open for ***SQL INJECTION***.You have to use ***`prepared statements`***

Help reference:-

[mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you very much